# Using playframework with the scala worksheet plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, worksheet

I tried to use the worksheet plugin in eclipse in combination with a play project but it doesn't seem to work. Every import is marked as not being found.

Has anyone got this working, is there anything special I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap, I had that problem. What I've done to solve it was:

1. If you're not using it, I would recommend you start using [Scala-IDE for eclipse](http://scala-ide.org/)
2. Even though I've previously got scala-ide, when I tried to use scala worksheet with a play project I still had that problem. I tried to do the default action to the scala worksheet plugin when you have a computer problem: reboot-update-reboot. And it worked! The version of Scala Worksheet that I'm currently using is (as seen in my Eclipse Installation details):

> Scala
>   Worksheet: 0.1.2.v-2_09-201210230838-85b738a

Check if your version is the same as mine. If it's try to remove it and install it againt. If it isn't, then try to update it. Tell me if it works.

Cheers!

Comment: Tried to reinstall and reboot several times and I have the exact same version, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

the question is a bit general, but:

if worksheet is working correctly without play framework => problem should lies in the installment of the framework:

1. did you update PATH (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Installing)?
2. is command `play help` working ?

You are asking about Play's Eclipse plugin specifically:
did you follow guide at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/ide#eclipse ?

Which step didn't work for you?

Comment: The worksheet is working fine using other projects (simple sbt ones for example). Play is in the path and play help is working. Eclipse is also working fine (debugging and code-completion are working).

The strange thing is, that eclipse also does code completion in the worksheet, but after saving the ws it can't find the imports.